# error in flask: Import error cannot import_name db

Tags: flask

I get this error in my command shell when I am trying to make a to-do-list app in pyhton, flask.

[comamnd shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE4Xv.png)

This is my app.py

[app.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA7QS.png)

I was mainly following a course on youtube about flask.
I'm a beginner so please try to include as much detail as possible.

Comment: Please insert your code as text instead of an image. It's  much easier for us to help you that way. Thank you.

Comment: that error is solved